# how to pass Angular JSON values on submit button for all checkbox values

Tags: angularjs

Below is my plunker edit. 
I was able to get checkbox values. Now I'm trying to pass those checked values onclick to http or inside ng-click=deleteSelected function.

http://plnkr.co/edit/wsd3oDr3SyQXvO8Fdh5F

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have bound the values to `$scope.checked-messages`, can't you just use the `$scope` in a click handler:

HTML:

```
<button id="btn-call" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="callTheServer()">Call The Server</button>
```

JS (Controller):

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {

  $scope.checked_messages = [];

  $scope.callTheServer = function() {

    console.log($scope.checked_messages);
  }
});
```

Here is an [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QSpZPX?p=preview).

Comment: That works. How do I post the same array to a php file ? Sorry I'm a newbie to AngularJS.

Comment: by `php file` I assume you mean the server. check out $http service.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your form in a  tag and declare your button as a submit type like this

```
<form ng-submit="deleteElements()">
  //checkboxes stuff
  <button id="btn-delete" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Now in your controller you declare your deleteElements function :

```
$scope.deleteElements = function(){
    console.log(this.checked_messages);
}
```

Answer from Davin is good but I try to avoid to bind everything to scope whenever I can.